# Swift, php and unicode characters

Tags: php, json, swift, serialization, unicode

I am using a url request to receive data from MySQL.
The data is received in a JSON format.
This data also includes unicode characters (for example greek letters).

Then, in Swift, I am using JSONSerialization like this:

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
```

The keys of json are number indices.
Then I take a nested dictionary like this:

```
let dictionary = json[key] as? [String: Any]
```

Then I assign:

```
var content = dictionary!["content"] as! String
```

This content has unicode characters inside it.

Unicode characters appear like this (if I print dictionary):
\U03b1 (for the greek letter Alpha).

The problem is that Swift cannot read those characters because Swift expects unicode characters to be like this: \u{03b1}.

The value of content is an empty string: ""

How can I solve this?
Either have PHP send those characters in the way the Swift "understands" them, or having Swift decoding the incoming data in the proper way.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Swift and JSONSerialization *can* handle Unicode escapes without problems. However, the server should send `\u03b1` with a lowercase u.

Comment: @MartinR it does return \u03b1 but Swift cannot read this correct as a String entity because it doesn't understand \u without curly brackets. Any idea?

Comment: Most probably this is just an artifact of how a *dictionary* (or *array*) is printed by default. Extract the string value  and print that.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I didn't think about it. I am simply getting an error when assigning this to a string: var content = dictionary["content"] as! String. Should I assign this differently?

Comment: What error? Please be more specific.

Comment: @MartinR Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' (0x102654ec0) to 'Swift.String.UTF16View'

Comment: I cannot guess. Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same kind of issue for multiple currency symbols. API team is passing now '\u0024' and it has resolved issue in Swift. May be you can try same from API side.